# Cohomology of Product of Spheres

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am trying to compute the De Rahm cohomology of $M = S^2 \times S^2$. I was able to compute $H^0(M), H^1(M),$ and $H^4(M)$, but am having trouble computing $H^2(M)$ and $H^3(M)$. I am using the Mayer Vietoris sequence, and I took $U = S^2 \times (S^2 \setminus \{p\})$ and $V  = S^2 \times (S^2 \setminus \{q\})$, so $U \cap V = S^2 \times S^1$. But I haven't been able to find any of the maps needed to compute $H^2$ or $H^3$. How can compute these groups?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Kunneth formula $H^2(S^2\times S^2)=H^0(S^2)\otimes H^2(S^2)\oplus H^1(S^2)\otimes H^1(S^2)\oplus H^0(S^2)\otimes H^2(S^2)=\mathbb{R}\oplus \mathbb{R}$,

the same formula gives $H^3(S^2\times S^2)=0$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Kunneth formula - can I do it without it?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that this is deRham cohomology is not so relevant once you understand how the maps are defined in terms of closed forms. So you know that $H^j(U) \cong H^j(S^2)$. What you need to do is figure out $H^j(U\cap V) \cong H^j(S^2\times S^1)$ by doing a Mayer-Vietoris decomposition on *that* first. You can do that either of two ways — either you need to know the cohomology of the torus ($S^1\times S^1$) or you break it down into $S^2\times \{p\}$ and $S^2\times\{p,q\}$, both of which you know.

Note that you'll be able to do $S^m\times S^n$ by such an inductive process. :)

Comment: Oh ... You should have disclosed that at the beginning. :) The easiest map to analyze (and all you'll need along with usual rank considerations) is the map $H^2(U)\oplus H^2(V)\to H^2(U\cap V)$. What is this map explicitly? You should be able to see it's surjective.

Comment: It's restricts a form on $U$ and a form on  $V$ to $U \cap V$, and it combines them by subtraction. But I don't see why its surjective.

Comment: Can't you write down a $2$-form on $U$ whose integral over $S^2\times \{\text{pt}\}\subset S^2\times S^1$ is nonzero?

Comment: I know one exists on $S^2$ and one exists on $S^1$ individually because they are orientable, but I'm not sure how to get one on $S^2 \times S^1$.

Comment: You can, for example, pull forms back by the projection map $S^2\times S^1 \to S^2$. And $S^2\times S^1\to S^1$. And wedge such things together, if it proves necessary (but what I'm proposing shouldn't involve that).

Comment: Could you be more explicit? I don't follow.

Comment: If $\omega$ is a $2$-form on $S^2$, and $\pi\colon S^2\times S^2\to S^2$ is projection on the first factor, then $\pi^*\omega$ is a $2$-form on $S^2\times S^2$. You can restrict it to $U$ if you want. You have a closed $2$-form on $U$; you might choose $\omega$ to have nonzero integral over $S^2$. Take the $0$-form on $V$. What can you say about the image of $([\omega],[0])\in H^2(U)\oplus H^2(V)$ in $H^2(S^2\times S^1)$?